# What is the proper way to stop Webpack in macOS?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have been using `Control C` but was hoping there was a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This question falls more under the realm of how to interact with a unix system, in this case, mac OS.

I dont see any inherent problem in using `ctrl+c` as what it would do is send the SIGINT to the webpack process, which, would be interpreted and handled, or kill the process. As long as you dont care about intermediate or incomplete results, you should be fine.

More on interruptions https://askubuntu.com/questions/510811/what-is-the-difference-between-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-c-in-the-terminal

Comment: thanks but I have to believe that webpack has a command to do this ?